# I want to change the icon of my android app's notification

Tags: java, android

I want to change the icon of my notification, i have tried the NotificationCompat.Builder's method setSmallIcon(int), but the icon don't change  [(screenshot of my app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IB9e.jpg) [(the icon i want to use)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfQj9.png), what can i do?

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentTitle("My notification")
           .setContentText("Hello World!")
           .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
           .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_stat_onesignal_default)
           .setLights(Color.WHITE, 300, 100)
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: What is the name of your icon in mipmap folder?

Comment: Hi @Patroid . You only need to save the second icon on the `Drawable Folder` and then use `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.second_icon)`

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhani it's ic_stat_onesignal_default.png

Comment: @Tonnie I tried, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try **File** --> **Invalidate Caches/ Restart ...** and see if the icon will change.

Comment: It didn't work, but i tried the app with other phones and on them it works, so probably it's a problem of my phone

Comment: @Patroid you are right. Sometimes some customized operating systems do these type of things. I think you should try on any other device instead of spending more time on it.